# badly resized partition on sd card

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, partition

when I installed Raspbian Stretch Lite `(2018-11-13)` on my 16GB SD card, with dd `(dd bs=4M if=2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.img of=/dev/sdb conv=fsync)` and then tried it, I quickly ran out of space so I checked it with `df -hl` and then with `parted` and this is what I got:

- df

  `/dev/root        1,7G  1,5G  105M  94% /
   devtmpfs         460M     0  460M   0% /dev
   tmpfs            464M     0  464M   0% /dev/shm
   tmpfs            464M   12M  452M   3% /run
   tmpfs            5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
   tmpfs            464M     0  464M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
   /dev/mmcblk0p1    44M   23M   22M  51% /boot
   tmpfs             93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1000
   total            3,6G  1,5G  2,1G  43% -`
- parted

  `1     4194kB    50,2MB  46,0MB   primary  fat32  LBA
   2     50,3MB    15,9GB  15,9GB   primary  ext4`

  where 1 is `boot` and 2 `rootfs`

Is it normal? How can I use whole SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listings you posted are inconsistent. 
It looks like the partition table was resized on initial boot, but the filesystem was not resized.

You could try `sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2` to adjust the partition.

If this is unsuccessful there is either something wrong with the image (did you check the checksum after downloading) or the card is faulty.

```
You COULD try rebooting to a root shell and can repair most such problems on the Pi.

1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot.
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as
read/write `mount -n -o remount,rw /`
```

Answer (score 0):

Get another SDCard and a fresh copy of Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-11-13 on it. Boot that in your RPi and `sudo apt install raspberrypi-ui-mods` (to give you a basic GUI) and `sudo apt install parted gparted` (Get gparted as the GUI version of parted is easier to use than the command line one.)

Get your 16GB SDCard in a USB reader, mount the USB reader in your RPi.

Use gparted to move and re-size the root partition to use all of the space.

Shutdown, swap cards, reboot, keep calm and carry on. Keep that spare SDCard as a rescue system for the next time you get in a mess.

You could do the same on your laptop with a gparted live CD/USB from [Gparted Live CD](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) booted instead of Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the instructions as in the link: https://thepi.io/how-to-install-raspbian-on-the-raspberry-pi/
Before that just format your sd cart properly so when you insert your cart again it will show you smth like 15,9 of 16,0 free.

Comment: That tutorial is ancient and I would not use or recommend it.

Comment: It worked fine for me

Comment: Some of the problems: it refers to Jessie, the downloads have changed considerably. The common names given to the images ('Raspbian Jessie with Pixel') cannot be found on the downloads page. You don't need to unzip if you use Etcher. Etcetera, etcetera. The main effect will be that it confuses a first time Pi user. Not helpful at all.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend doing a clean install, using this guide [on the RaspPi website.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/)  Use Etcher, insert the microSD card into a reader which connects to USB, and it should reformat and flash your card.

Etcher doesn't require anything, it does it all for you. So you won't have to worry about the format or partitions.

For the adapter, you could get a microSD to SD adapter, and a SD card usb reader, insert the microSD into the adapter and the SD adapter into the usb reader, then run Etcher on that drive.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the OP's problem as they're trying to make a copy of their existing system to gain more space.